# reliability of a device for my thesis and negative icc values in spss

Tags: spss, reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

first time here , hoping for a great answer!

so my thesis is including using a sensor to measure how far is a a person leg is from the sensor. 
so i measured it with a ruler and compared with sensor reading.
took 5 arbitrary lengths, made 3 reading of each, for 5 different days.
i also got a co-worker that did the same to help me later.
so now i want to check if my results are the same of my colleague and if our results repeat it self each day.
some of the results we got was completely similar to each other (the ruler compared to the sensor)

so now my question is- what's the correct way to enter that data into spss to get the information i described?

thanks !
Tomer